# My php session is acting weird

Tags: php, session

It looks like I still haven't got the grasp on sessions.
Session data will simply not be accessible for included files or stored when page is reloaded.

I have the following code:

page1.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Some template
*/

  session_start();  
  $_SESSION['start'] = 'start';
  print_r($_SESSION);

  if(some condition)      
    include('include1.php');
  else
    include('include2.php');
?>
```

include1.php

```
<?php
  /* Some comments here */

  $_SESSION['test'] = 'Test text';
  print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

include2.php

```
<?php
  /* Some comments here */

  print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Page1 first includes `include1.php` where I do some stuff. Then I load page1 including `include2.php`.

The output result of the `print_r()` is:

```
Array ( [start] => start ) // From page 1
Array ( [start] => start [test] => Test text )  // From include 1
Array ( [start] => start ) // From include 2
```

**My question is:**
1) Why isn't `[include]` outputted in page1.php in the first `print_r()`after reload?
2) Why isnt' `[include]`outputted in include2.php?

I only add `session_start()` in page 1 since the other two files are included. I've also tried adding `session_start()` in both include files, but that doesn't work either, since it creates new instances.

**UPDATE**
My "actuall" include code:

```
  switch($action) {
    case 'a': include_once('include/include1.php'); break;
    case 'b': include_once('include/include2.php'); break;
    //default:  
  }
  print_r($_SESSION); // <- Here all registered session variables are outputed
```

Comment: What you show should work. You using a file path to include, not `http://`?

Comment: @pekka - That shouldn't be a problem, should it? `include` works fine that way.

Comment: @eykanal a script included through `http://` will run in its own, separate PHP process, which doesn't share the initial script's session data.

Comment: @Pekka I'm not using file path (I never use that). Is there a way to share session data using `http://` ?

Comment: You don't have a second `session_start` somewhere?

Comment: @morgar Typos :) Should be include1 and include2

Comment: @Steven `http://` includes are a bad idea because they work fundamentally differently from local ones. They run as independent scripts. But if `include/include1.php` is the actual path you use in your project, you are using a (relative) file path

Comment: I just tried this on my own server, and I was unable to replicate this problem using the code you posted (switching between `if(true)` and `if(false)` on reloads). Try adding the lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your code to see if you're missing something more fundamental.

Comment: @pekka Yes, I'm using relative file path. So there must be something else. I will look to see if I'm using `session_start()` somewhere else.

Comment: @eykanal Thanks for that. I found some errors, but nothing I could see that was related to sessions. But I will fix the errors and see what happends.

Comment: @pekka, I'm able to output all session variables if I do a `print_r()` after the `switch`. But I should be able to output any session variable in my include files as well, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you displayed is working the way it is supposed to:

You initialized sessions - `session_start()`

You created the first element in the array - `start`

On the first include, you added an array element to $_SESSION by adding the key `test`

When you output the first include, it includes both `start` and `test`

On the second include, you did not add any array elements to $_SESSION, which is why it outputs only `start`

The include code you stated only calls in the first page, or the second page, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

try using session_name and session_id

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: How does this address the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that cookies are not being saved. Check the cookies in your browser for `PHPSESSID` or similar. If that cookie is never getting set, it is likely because you are trying to start your session AFTER headers have been sent. Enabling warnings will show you that this is the case.

Headers will be send by PHP as soon as you start normal output. Thus, if in `page1` you have this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<html>";

    // Session starts here...
?>
```

Then the session cannot be saved to the client side and will start at nothing every time the user loads the page. A similar situtation happens if you have whitespace in a file before or after the PHP start/end tags.

Comment: The session variables should be available on all pages for the user, not just the current one. So when I load `include1.php` a session variable is set which should be available in `include2.php`.

Comment: @Steven, sorry, I got the problem now. Updated answer.

Comment: @Kevin Peno - I'm calling `get_header(); ` after `session_start()`, so it. I've got multiple `<?php ?>` in different files and it's bound to be white space before / after the tags if they are in between code.

Comment: @Steven, if it's a "after headers sent" issue, then it should be apparent by turning on `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set("display_errors",true);`. Put that at the top of your page and you will see a warning if PHP tries to send headers "late"

Comment: @Kevin Peno, I think you read it wrong. `session_start()` is **before** I call `get_header()`. I've just discovered that I can output all session variables after my `switch` statement that includes the other files. But still not able to output all the session vars if I do a `print_f()` at the top of my `page1.php`.

Comment: `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set("display_errors",true);` shows no errors.